# Go main function not operated first

Tags: go, program-entry-point, process.start

```
package main
import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "strings"
    "unicode/utf8"
    "sync"
    "github.com/robfig/cron"
     cpu "github.com/shirou/gopsutil/cpu"
    "fmt"
)

const NumofResource = 4

// 구조체
type HostInfo struct {
    Hostid string
}

var c *cron.Cron
var lastCPUTimes []cpu.TimesStat

func main() {
    fmt.Println("1.main.go > main() start")
    defer l4g.Close()

var err interface{}
lastCPUTimes, err = cpu.Times(false) //nil
fmt.Println("2.main.go > err", err)
fmt.Println("3.main.go > lastCPUTimes", lastCPUTimes)

if err != nil {
    l4g.Error(err)
}
}
```

I know that the main function is executed first.
However, we confirmed that the library called cpu_windows.go is executed first.
Why?

> cpu_windows.go : Times(bool) false
>
> cpu_windows.go : common.ProcGetSystemTimes.Call  1
>
> cpu_windows.go : Times(bool) true
>
> cpu_windows.go : return perCPUTimes()
>
> 1.main.go : main() start
>
> cpu_windows.go : Times(bool) false
>
> cpu_windows.go : common.ProcGetSystemTimes.Call  1
>
> 2.main.go : err

Answer (score 1):

The [specification says](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_initialization):

> If a package has imports, the imported packages are initialized before initializing the package itself.

and

> Program execution begins by initializing the main package and then invoking the function main.

It follows that the [initialization code](https://github.com/shirou/gopsutil/blob/084e5f47b47ee4dce70b1cafa83c13027e9e9483/cpu/cpu.go#L55-L61) in the imported `cpu` package is executed before any code in `main`.